# Aviary sdk error

Tags: android, aviary

Whenever I import **aviary SDK**. it shows an error like this in

```
com.aviary.android.feather.widget/VibrationWidget.java

Error is in this line package com.aviary.android.feather.widget;

Error:The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class     files
```

I cannot successfully import **aviary SDK**.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Could you please help on doing aviary editor in android app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with downloading the sdk from the site. Whenever i was downloading it some files were missing. project.properties file was missing. I copied it from another project and in aviary setup guide(https://developers.aviary.com/docs/android/setup-guide)
they tell us to add

```
target=android-18
android.library=false
android.library.reference.1=../Aviary-SDK
```

I added the above on project.properties. And the error has been solved. I posted this because maybe sometimes this will help